# Can you exclude certain files from being uploaded in an R shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, file-io, upload

I am working on a shiny app where the user uploads a number of csv files based on which some output is created. The files to upload are produced by an external application and all lie in the same folder. I want the user to be able to select all files in the folder for upload and I am currently using
`shiny::fileInput()` with the option `multiple = TRUE` in the shiny App.

[image]

The problem I have is that the output folder contains a file that can be quite large and that is not required for the analysis in the app. The app works fine if the user just deselects that file in the upload menu. But I was wondering if there is a way that I can tell the app to **ignore a certain file** (based on the file name), so that even if the user selects all files in the folder for upload, the large file is **not uploaded** while all the other selected files still are.

I know that you can set a maximum file size in the options (`shiny.maxRequestSize`) but this does not seem to solve my problem, as the upload then ends with an error if the large file is selected.

Here is a minimal example of the app:

```
library(shiny)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 30*1024^2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      # Upload menu is created here:
      fileInput(
        inputId = "upload",
        label = "Upload Files", 
        buttonLabel = "Select files...", 
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput(outputId = "files")
    )
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$files <- renderTable(
    input$upload[, c("name", "size")]
  ) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```